# Python Eve - Datetime filtering not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, curl, eve

I am using EVE 1.1.1, python 3.8 and curl 7.68.0

I have a curl GET request which works fine on **Windows 10** but when I try to run it on Ubuntu **Linux 20.04** I get an HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST error.

I have changed the `DATE_FORMAT` setting to `"%d/%m/%y"` in the `settings.py file`.

Nevertheless, when I remove the datetime filter it works fine on Linux as well.

**My curl GET request is the following:**

```
curl -g -H "Authorization: my_auth_token" -i "localhost:1010/my_data?where={%22date%22:%20{%22$eq%22:%2224/06/2020%22}}&pretty"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

It seems that Ubuntu was interpreting `$eq` in the filtering string as an environmental variable due to the `$` character.

In order to be able to execute the GET request I encoded the the `$` character to urlencoded format which is `%24`.

**Therefore, my curl GET request has the following format:**

```
curl -g -H "Authorization: my_auth_token" -i "localhost:1010/my_data?where={%22date%22:%20{%22%24eq%22:%2224/06/2020%22}}&pretty"
```